# Golang template for source and target printing

Tags: templates, go

I want to generate go template with loop which looks like following

```
target1:
   echo from target2 
target2:
  echo from target2 
targetN:
  echo from targetN
```

This simply creates a target and line after
it prints from which target it's called.

I've tried with the following which works partially, any Idea what I miss here ? or how can I simplify the code in  `t.Execute`
https://play.golang.org/p/iLWQANobKUL

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
)

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(` {{- range .}} {{.Name}}:{{end}}
{{- range .}}
{{.Name}}:
{{"\t"}}echo from {{.Name}} {{.Text}}
{{end}}
`))
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    t.Execute(&buf, []interface{}{map[string]string{"Name": "target1", "Text": "echo"}})
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", buf.String())
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
package main

import (
    "text/template"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`{{- range .}}{{.}}:
    echo from {{.}}
{{end}}
`))
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, []string{"target1", "target2", "target3"})
}
```

Output:

```
target1:
    echo from target1
target2:
    echo from target2
target3:
    echo from target3
```

Ref: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

**Update:**

If you want to use the pipeline as a map and want to use value from the value of the corresponding key, then:

```
package main

import (
    "text/template"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`{{- range $key, $val := .}}{{$key}}:
    echo from {{$val}}
{{end -}}
`))
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, map[string]string{"target1": "foo1", "target2": "bar2", "target3": "baz"})
}
```

Output:

```
target1:
    echo from foo1
target2:
    echo from bar2
target3:
    echo from baz
```

Comment: yes 1+, thanks a lot. btw if I want to use some key value i mean everthing is the same but just the value of the echo will be the value, i.e. {target1:foo1 ,target2:bar2,target3:baz}`  and the complite  value will be the same just the echo for targets like `target2` echo will be `echo from bar2` and for `target3` will be `echo from baz`

Comment: Welcome! Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you again :) , I've another question which is related, please see if you can help , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461812/golang-write-template-into-file